# What are the consequences of dying in faction wars

Tags: albion-online

In general, dying in blue or yellow zones does not make you lose your equipment, while you do red and black zones.

However, I noticed that there sometimes is a pile of silver next to my body when I die while participating in faction wars, which is a bit unexpected for me.

Is that the only consequence of dying?